# Limit of 3 variable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have to determine the following limit:
$$\lim_{(x,y,z)\rightarrow\infty}\left(x^4+y^2+z^2-x^3+xyz-x+4\right)$$

My approach was to use the spheric coordinates in order to see if the limit depends on $\phi$ and $\theta$.

$x=r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\\
y=r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\\
z=r\cos(\phi)\\
z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

and so i ended up with the following term:
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}(r^4\sin^4(\theta)\cos^4(\phi)+r^2\sin^2(\theta)\sin^2(\phi)+r^2\cos^2(\phi)-r^3\sin^3(\theta)\cos^3(\phi)+r^3\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\phi)\sin(\phi)-r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)+4)$$

As I see it there is no reduction of this formula such that the limit is not dependant on $\phi$ and $\theta$. And therefore the limit is not defined.

Is this correct or am I missing something?
Or is there even a better way to determine the limit of the given term?

Comment: Why not simply plug in the sequence $(n,n,n)$ and let $n\to\infty$? Then you see that the limit is not finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $$x^4+y^2+z^2-x^3+xyz-x+4\geq$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+x^4-x^3-x^2-x+4\geq x^2+y^2+z^2\rightarrow+\infty.$$
We used that:
$$x^4-x^3-x^2-x+4=\left(x^2-\frac{1}{2}x-1\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}(3x^2-8x+12)>0.$$